# Linear application on a normed space

Tags: general-topology, normed-spaces

How to prove that if  $E$ and $F$ are tow normed spaces with $dim(F)<\infty$ and $f\in L(E,F)$

Then $$f~ \text{open} \Longleftrightarrow f ~\text{surjective}$$

If i suppose that $f$ is open, then $U=f(B_{E}(0,1))$ is open so there exist $r>0$ such that $B_{F}(0,r)\subset U$ then $$\forall y\in F, \frac{ry}{2||y||_{F}}\in B_{F}(0,r)\subset U\subset f(E)$$ So ther exists $x\in E, f(x)=\frac{ry}{2||y||_{F}}$i.e $\displaystyle\exists x\in E, y=f\left(\frac{2||y||_{F}}{r}x\right)$ 
So $f$ is surjective right ?

If i suppose that $f$ is surjective: $dim(F)=n<\infty$ so $\{f_1,...,f_n\}$ is a basis for $F$ as $f$ is surjective there existe a basis $\{e_1,...,e_n\}$ such that $f(e_i)=f_i$ then $f:G\rightarrow F$ where $G=\langle\{e_1,...,e_n\}\rangle$

**But how to continue?????**

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Suppose $f$ open**. The image of the unit open ball is open. In particular contains an open ball centered on the origin of radius $2\alpha$. Therefore contains all the vectors $\alpha f_1,\dots,\alpha f_n$ where $(f_1,\dots,f_n)$ is a basis of $F$ of vectors having norms equal to $1$. Hence $f$ is surjective as supposed to be linear.

**Conversely, suppose $f$ surjective.**
For $1 \le i \le n$, take $e_i \in E$ with $f(e_i)=f_i$. $(e_1,\dots,e_n)$ is a basis of a subspace $E^\prime \subset E$. The restriction $f^\prime$ of $f$ to $E^\prime$ is a bijective linear map between spaces of finite dimensions. Hence $f^\prime$ is continuous as is $(f^\prime)^{-1}$. Now take an open ball $B \subset E$ centered at the origin. $B \cap E^\prime$ is an open ball of $E^\prime$ centered at the origin. As $(f^\prime)^{-1}$ is continuous $f(B \cap E^\prime)$ is open. Hence $f(B)$ is open.

Comment: i don't understand As $f'^{-1}$ is continuous $f(B \cap E^\prime)$ is open ? what is the relation with $f'$ ???

Comment: @Vrouvrou $B \cap E^\prime$ is open in $E^\prime$. And $f(B \cap E^\prime)$ is equal to the inverse image of $B \cap E^\prime$ under $(f^\prime)^{-1}$.

Comment: Why? i don't understand

Comment: Let $X^\prime \subset E^\prime$. By definition the inverse image of $X^\prime$ under $(f^\prime)^{-1}$ is $[(f^\prime)^{-1}]^{-1}(X^\prime)=\{y \in F : \ (f^\prime)^{-1}(y) \in X^\prime\}$ and because $f^\prime$ is a bijection $\{y \in F : \ (f^\prime)^{-1}(y) \in X^\prime\}=f^\prime(X^\prime)$. Then you can apply this to $X^\prime=B \cap E^\prime$.

Comment: So you foud that $f'(B(0,1)\cap E')$ is open because $f'(B(0,1)\cap E')$ is equal to the inverse image of $B\cap E'$ under $(f')^{-1}$ how to obtain that $f(B)$ is open ?